# To edit profile before i have to retrieve a data from database in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

```
<table>
    <tr> 
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('firstname',array('type' => 'text','value'=>$firstname));?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('lastname',array('type' => 'text','value' => $lastname)); ?>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username',array('type' => 'text','value'=>$username));?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('gender',array('type' => 'select','value' => $gender)); ?>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('email',array('type' => 'text','value'=>$email));?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('dateofbirth',array('type' => 'date','dateFormat' => 'YMD','value' => $dateofbirth)); ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Mobile',array('type' => 'text','value' => $mobile)); ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php  echo $this->Form->end('Save'); ?>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I retrieved all data and put in the text box, but I don't know how to select a radio button

```
echo $this->Form->input('gender',array('type' => 'select','value' => $gender)); ?>
```

And a dropdown box also

```
echo $this->Form->input('dateofbirth',array('type' => 'date','dateFormat' => 'YMD','value' => $dateofbirth)); ?>
```

Please Help these two things. I am using Cakephp 2.5.4 version.

Comment: You mean you want to have you radio button and your dropdown with preselected values when the page loads?

Comment: yes sir can u help  me this question???